# EC2 instance randomly crash

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mariadb

My EC2 instance kept crashing, here is the syslog, can server admin expert share some insight?

https://pastebin.com/jfP8qhZX

Comment: Is there any good reason to have 2 newrelc-daemon's running?  pid 1535 and 1538?

Answer (score 0):

Is your EC2 instance crashing, or is an application being terminated?

I'm not really an expert in this area, but looking at your logs for 10 seconds I can see that the instance is running out of memory and is being terminated by the operating system. If I looked for another 10 seconds I might find something else. I could be completely wrong.

```
Mar 28 14:32:16 ip-172-31-27-212 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Mar 28 14:32:16 ip-172-31-27-212 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Mar 28 14:32:16 ip-172-31-27-212 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Mar 28 14:32:16 ip-172-31-27-212 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 58min 33.512s CPU time.
```

You really need to share more details about the problem, symptoms, instance size, etc, if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

What is result from MySQL query of SELECT @@connect_timeout; ?

If the answer is 10, in your Parameter Group, change the value to 30 to extend allowable time for a connection to be successful.

You have 0 SWAP space in your Ubuntu OS setup.  You will likely be required to ASK AWS to provide 20% SWAP space (3.2G minimum) to avoid OOM experienced today.  Unless you have an unmanaged EC2 instance, then you should have root access to make your own SWAP space available.  It is much better to run a few seconds slow than face Out Of Memory and all the troubles that come with OOM failures.